# why does marquee delay when an ajax response receive

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a marquee which scrolls dynamic data in my web application, which halts a bit starts scrolling again, its like someone stops it and drags again kind of a behavior when other ajax responses receive and update data in html page. Is this a issue with marquee tag?

```
<marquee scrollamount="1" scrolldelay="10">
    <span id="HPQ" class="syPrice">22.20</span>
    <span id="APQ" class="ayPrice">12.20</span>
    <span id="BPQ" class="byPrice">18.10</span>
    <span id="CPQ" class="cyPrice">65.20</span>
    <span id="DPQ" class="dyPrice">87.56</span>
    <span id="EPQ" class="eyPrice">15.24</span>
    <span id="FPQ" class="fyPrice">34.45</span>
    <span id="GPQ" class="gyPrice">16.20</span>
</marquee>
```

and my ajax calls responses continuously updates this page as well.

```
function dataUpdate(){
          $.ajax({
                  type : "GET",
                   url : '../myJsonData.xhtml',
                  dataType : "json",
                  async : true,
                  cache : false,

                  success: function(data) {
                     $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                      /* updates data here */
                     });
                  setTimeout('dataUpdate()',1000);
                  },
                  error : function() {
              }
             });
          }
```

I update the marquee data in similar manner like above ajax call

Comment: Isn't the marquee tag deprecated/nonstandard?

Comment: @PhonicUK it was never fully official. Just use javascript or css animations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not an issue with the marquee tag specifically.

The browser only does one thing at a time in the user interface. As long as a script is running, there are no updates at all in the page.

If you have any other moving element, for example an animated GIF, you would see that they would also pause for a bit while the script is running.

Comment: is there anyway that i can overcome this issue

Comment: @Swarnajith: No, that's how browsers work. You can try to make the script run faster to make the delay less noticable. You can for example keep the data in an array (or similar) and compare the old values to the new values, and only update the elements if the values actually has changed.

Comment: If I add a jquery scroller instead of marquee will it result the same?

Comment: I only update the data if there's a change. The thing is its a bit noticeable to the users

Comment: @Swarnajith: Yes. Any kind of animation will react the same.